# Arithmatic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert data from one table to another table, but we are facing issue it gives us error of

> `Numeric value out of range: 8115 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server ]Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to
>   data type numeric. (SQLExecDirect[8115] at /builddir
>   /build/BUILD/php-5.6.30/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:247)`

We are using below query to insert data

```
`INSERT INTO template_150  ([ClientName],[LOB],[PharmacyTotalClaimAmt])
 SELECT PharmacyID,ProductIDNDC
,  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(varchar(10),LEFT
(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(IngredCost),'\',''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%',REPLACE(TRIM(IngredCost),'\','')),
 8000),PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(REPLACE(TRIM(IngredCost),'\',''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%',REPLACE
(TRIM(IngredCost),'\','')), 8000) + 'X') -1)) )
),'"',''),'$',''),',',''),'-','') AS [TRIM(IngredCost)]  
FROM file_5979bd211a3a9`
```

I found some solution to use lenth `WHERE  LEN(IngredCost
)<=13` function in where condition, but if we will use this function then we will not able to insert all the records for the table `file_5979bd211a3a9`, we want to save all the records of table `file_5979bd211a3a9`, can anyone please give us solutio, how can we resolve this error ?

Comment: Hi, provide data samples and expected results. Also both tables structure

Comment: Please format the code better in your description, it's hard to read

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would really like to help you but you haven't provided any details required for somebody to really help here. Are you trying to load all the rows from your table into another table? We need a LOT more information. Like table definitions, sample data etc....

Comment: Inside single SELECT column you have 8 times REPLACE, 3x CONVERT, 2 SUBSTRINGs, 4 TRIMs and 3 times PATINDEX! If you can't tell where is the error in there, do you honestly expect someone else to be able to read that and tell you how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what type `IngredCost` is, show few sample rows and what do you expect to get in result? There has to be an easier way.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic IngredCost  column datatype is varchar, the issue is we don't know the value of that column it can be the any of the lenth, it can be alphabatic, when we insert that data to this column  `PharmacyTotalClaimAmt`, this column datatype is decimal,its numeric precson is 18, so if the value is more than its lenth then at that time it gives arithmatic overflow error, what i need to do, if its length is bigger than we want to convert its as per the length of the column `PharmacyTotalClaimAmt` , so it can be insert in the table

Comment: @NenadZivkovic i used replace because `IngredCost` can be alphanumeric, so i want to remove all the non numeric characters from the string, we will only consider 0-9, and dot, so i used replace function

Comment: What value of `IngredCost` is causing the out of range exception, and what do you want to insert when that value is encountered?   If there are more than one, then provide at least one example.

Comment: @TabAlleman , we don't know the value of IngredCost, that is the issue, i need solution that whatever it's value i need to insert it as decimal, i am replacing non numeric characters from the string

Comment: Yes but if you can't give us an example of a value that breaks your script, we can't help you fix it.   Questions about why a piece of code isn't working must include all the information necessary to reproduce the issue.   Your issue is not reproducible, so how can we help you?

Answer (score 1):

You're converting a 10 character number to a `DECIMAL(10,2)`.  That means up to 8 digits in the whole portion and 2 in the fractional.  If there are more than 8 numbers in the whole portion of the number, you can't convert that to a `DECIMAL(10,2)`.

For example:

```
 select convert(decimal(10,2),'1000000000')
```

Try `DECIMAL(12,2)` or use a `VARCHAR(8)`.

Comment: IngredCost column datatype is varchar, the issue is we don't know the value of that column it can be the any of the lenth, it can be alphabatic, when we insert that data to this column PharmacyTotalClaimAmt, this column datatype is decimal,its numeric precson is 18, so if the value is more than its lenth then at that time it gives arithmatic overflow error, what i need to do, if its length is bigger than we want to convert its as per the length of the column PharmacyTotalClaimAmt , so it can be insert in the table